# Creating a zoo object from a csv file (with a few inconsistencies) with R

Tags: r, csv, zoo

I am trying to create a zoo object in R from the following csv file:
http://www.cboe.com/publish/scheduledtask/mktdata/datahouse/Skewdailyprices.csv

The problem seems to be that there are a few minor inconsistencies in the period from 2/27/2006 to 3/20/2006 (some extra commas and an "x") that lead to problems.

I am looking for a method that reads the complete csv file into R automatically. There is a new data point every business day and when doing manual prepocessing you would have to re-edit the file every day by hand.

I am not sure if these are the only problems with this file but I am running out of ideas how to create a zoo object out of this time series. I think that with some more knowledge of R it should be possible.

Comment: Have you tried editing those _sixteen lines_ by hand in a text editor and then trying again?

Comment: No, I haven't because I am looking for a method that reads the csv file into R automatically. There is a new data point every business day and you would have to re-edit every time by hand...

Comment: In that case, perhaps your question should reflect your actual problem...?

Comment: My suggestion disappeared with Richie's answer. I have to run, but someone else can pick this up and write an answer if they like: try using `readLines`, process each one using `lapply` and then stick them back together with `do.call`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `colClasses` to tell it that there are 4 fields and use `fill` so it knows to fill them if they are missing on any row.  Ignore the warning:

```
library(zoo)
URL <- "http://www.cboe.com/publish/scheduledtask/mktdata/datahouse/Skewdailyprices.csv"
z <- read.zoo(URL, sep = ",", header = TRUE, format = "%m/%d/%Y", skip = 1, 
         fill = TRUE, colClasses = rep(NA, 4))
```

Answer (score 3):

It is a good idea to separate the cleaning and analysis steps.  Since you mention that your dataset changes often, this cleaning must be automatic.  Here is a solution for autocleaning.

```
#Read in the data without parsing it
lines <- readLines("Skewdailyprices.csv")

#The bad lines have more than two fields 
n_fields <- count.fields(
  "Skewdailyprices.csv", 
  sep = ",", 
  skip = 1
)

#View the dubious lines
lines[n_fields != 2]

#Fix them
library(stringr) #can use gsub from base R if you prefer
lines <- str_replace(lines, ",,x?$", "")

#Write back out to file
writeLines(lines[-1], "Skewdailyprices_cleaned.csv")

#Read in the clean version
sdp <- read.zoo(
    "Skewdailyprices_cleaned.csv", 
    format = "%m/%d/%Y", 
    header = TRUE, 
    sep = ","
)
```

Comment: Huh. This throws an error for me. I was going to suggest using `readLines` and then processing them via `lapply` to remove problem rows.

Comment: @joran: Not sure what I did, but my first answer was nonsense.  This version seems to work.